# how to filter and sum using linq

Tags: c#, linq

what is the best LINQ approach for with no performance loss? how could we do the same thing using LINQ iterating the list only once?

```
class Employee  
{  
    string name ...;  
    string age .....;  
    int empType ...;  
    int income ...;  
}  

List<Employee> myList ...;  
List<Employee> toList...;  
int totalIncomeOfToList = 0;  

foreach(Employee emp in myList)  
{  
    if(emp.empType == 1)  
    {  
        toList.Add(emp);  
        totalIncomeOfToList += emp.income;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: get the trial period of resharper

Comment: Thank You for the solution guys. Happy to see quick responses for my first post.

Answer (score 13):

(I'm assuming you *want* the filtered list as well - the other answers given so far only end up with the sum, not the list as well. They're absolutely fine if you don't need the list, but they're not equivalent to your original code.)

Well you can iterate over the *original* list just once - and then iterate over the *filtered* list afterwards:

```
var toList = myList.Where(e => e.empType == 1).ToList();
var totalIncomeOfToList = toList.Sum(e => e.income);
```

Admittedly this could be a *bit* less efficient in terms of blowing through the processor cache twice, but I'd be surprised if it were significant. If you can prove that it *is* significant, you can always go back to the "manual" version.

You *could* write a projection with a side-effect in it, to do it all in one pass, but that's so ugly that I won't even include it in the answer unless I'm really pressed to do so.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that populates the `toList`. I think that was the real problem why the question was asked.

Comment: Thanks Jon. You are right. I want the filtered list as well as the sum. Your solution is exactly what I had in my mind. However, I wanted to know if there is a solution that would match the same performance.

Comment: @user2907465: The performance difference is likely to be insignificant. I would use this and then find out whether or not this is actually a performance hit.

Comment: @user2907465 `LINQ` is never faster than the traditional loop with correct data structure, It can save you memory but always a little slower than traditional loop with some already-in-memory data, at least that's what I've experienced.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for getting the total income

```
var totalIncomeOfToList = myList.Where(e => e.empType == 1).Sum(e => e.income);
```

If you also want the list of filtered employees then:

```
var toList = myList.Where(e => e.empType == 1).ToList();
var totalIncomeOfToList = toList.Sum(e => e.income);
```

The performance will be slightly better with a foreach, but this way the code will be much clear and precise.

Answer (score 1):

I know LINQ should not have side-effects, but for what it's worth ...

```
int totalIncomeOfToList = 0;  
List<Employee> toList = myList
    .Where(emp => emp.empType == 1)
    .Select(emp => { totalIncomeOfToList += emp.income; return emp; })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Is this same as Jon's solution under the hood?

Comment: @Nith: I assume that it's what Jon mentioned in his last sentence("but that's so ugly that...") ;-)