# How can I sum the values of a member in a generic list based on the value of another member?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, sum, where-clause

I've got this generic list:

```
private List<ItemsForMonthYear> _itemsForMonthYearList;
```

...which stores instantiations of this class:

```
public class ItemsForMonthYear
{
    public String ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public String monthYr { get; set; }
    public int TotalPackages { get; set; }
    public Decimal TotalPurchases { get; set; }
    public Decimal AveragePrice { get; set; }
    public Double PercentOfTotal { get; set; }
}
```

I need to calculate the totals for all the TotalPackages in the list for each month (separately). I've got a start with this:

```
private int GetGrandTotalPackagesForMonth(String YYYYMM)
{
    return _itemsForMonthYearList.Sum(x => x.TotalPackages);
}
```

This, though, gets the Grand TotalPackages for *all* months; I just want (one at a time) the Grand Totals for a given month. I was hoping I could use "Where" something like this:

```
return _itemsForMonthYearList.Sum(x => x.TotalPackages).Where(x => x.monthYr == YYYYMM);
```

...but that is not available.

How can I restrict a summation to the specified month?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to filter and sum using linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520993/how-to-filter-and-sum-using-linq)

Comment: Elementary question with trivial answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should apply the filter first and then sum `TotalPackages` like:

```
return _itemsForMonthYearList.Where(x => x.monthYr == YYYYMM).Sum(x => x.TotalPackages);
```

Although not related, but if you want you can get the sum for each month in a single query using `GroupBy` like:

```
var sumForeachMonth = _itemsForMonthYearList.GroupBy(x => x.monthYr)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Month = grp.Key,
        Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.TotalPackages)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have Where clause available for such operations

```
myList.Where(x => x. monthYr == "Nov-15").Sum(x => x.TotalPackages);
```