# how can Get Sum of selected Fields by Id Linq C#?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var totalDistributed = db.Distributions
                         .Select(m => m.Product.ProductName == (string)productNameComboBox.SelectedItem).Any()
                         ? db.Distributions.Sum(m => m.Piece) : 0;

var totalStock = db.StockIns
                   .Select(m => m.Product.ProductName == (string)productNameComboBox.SelectedItem)
                   .Any() ? db.StockIns.Sum(m => m.Piece) : 0;
```

Using this code, I get the sum of all values, but I want to get sum of specific values through `productId` using a linq query. `productId` comes from `productNameComboBox`.

Comment: Use `Where` and then `Sum`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to filter and sum using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520993/how-to-filter-and-sum-using-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Where filter function instead of Select if Where filter function does not find any matches, Sum will return 0.

```
var totalDistributed = db.Distributions
                         .Where(m => m.Product.ProductName == (string)productNameComboBox.SelectedItem).Sum(m => m.Piece);

var totalStock = db.StockIns
                   .Where(m => m.Product.ProductName == (string)productNameComboBox.SelectedItem).Sum(m => m.Piece);
```